# pass command line arguments to python interpreter without a script file

Tags: python

I want do start the python interpreter and debug with sys.argv. I do not want to provide a python file. If I provide a file, the interpreter executes the file and finishes.

Is there a way to archive this?

```
python argA argB
...
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.argv
['argA','argB']
```

Comment: use `mock`'s `patch` function to replace `sys.argv` with another list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty much what you want:

```
$ python - argA argB
```

The first argument will show up as `-`, though - think of it as a pseudo script name. I don't think you can get away from that.

Comment: this might be even better! (does not influence the code I'm debugging if i do copy&paste my "consol-research" into working project!!!)